# Remove "queue:///" from destination name Apache Camel + IBM MQ

Tags: apache-camel, jms, ibm-mq

Using apache camel I am sending mesasge to IBM Queue `Q001IN`, but at the other end the application is validating for the destination and they are expecting destination as `Q001IN` however they are receiving as queue:///Q001IN instead of Q001IN.

```
...
.to("jms:Q001IN")
.end()
```

Is there anyway I can override this to remove queue:/// ?

I tried below but it does not work.

```
.setHeader("destination", simple("QUEUE_NAME"))
.setHeader("destinationName", simple("QUEUE_NAME"))
.to("jms:Q001IN")
```

Comment: Not getting the picture here. The "other end" must be receiving the messages that you write to the queue, not the queue name itself, right?

Comment: yes that's right, they are receiving the message but for validating the message they are using `((Queue)getJMSDestination).getQueueName() to check if it came from valid queue or not,

Answer (score 1):

Your receiver application receives a [JMS Destination](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Destination.html) object, a [JMS Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/Queue.html), to be exact. What you see as "queue:///" is the toString() of that object. If you want to get to the queue name, you must (unfortunately), cast the destination object to `javax.jms.Queue` and then use method `Queue.getQueueName()`. I'm not sure about your receiving application, but let's say **dest** contains the JMSDestination of your received Message:

```
import javax.jms.Queue
Queue q = (Queue)dest;
String qName = q.getQueueName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the other applications are using IBM MQ Specific API and Headers. That's the reason they are able to retrieve only queue name. If i send message using below they are able to receive queue name without queue:///

```
    Hashtable<String, Object> properties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    properties.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, HOST);
    properties.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, new Integer(PORT));
    properties.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, CHANNEL);
    MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(QUEUE_MANAGER, properties);
    int openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;
    com.ibm.mq.MQQueue ibmQueue = queueManager.accessQueue(QUEUE_NAME, openOptions);
    MQMessage msg = new MQMessage();
    MQRFH2 rfh2 = new MQRFH2();
    rfh2.setFieldValue("mcd", "Msd", "jms_text");
    rfh2.setFieldValue("jms", "Dst", QUEUE_NAME);
    rfh2.write(msg);
    msg.writeString("This is using IBM API : " + System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000);
    msg.format = CMQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2;
    MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
    ibmQueue.put(msg, pmo);
```

And even if i use JMS API as below.

```
        JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
        JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
        cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QUEUE_MANAGER);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
        cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
        JMSContext context = cf.createContext();
        Queue destination = context.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);

        TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("This is using JMS API" + System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000);
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(destination, message);
        System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);
        System.out.println("JMSDestination : " + ((Queue) message.getJMSDestination()).getQueueName());
```

and try to case destination to queue and get the queue name i am getting

`queue:///<Queue_Name>`

Below is the output

```
This is using JMS API456
JMSDestination : queue:///<Queue_Name>
```

When i was trying to browse both message one sent using jms and other using ibm mq

The destination is different for both as shown below.

[image]